# Getting NullPointerException for querySummary method while calculating data usage

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, usagestatsmanager, networkstatsmanager

I'm using querySummary() method of NetworkStatsManager to calculate the data usage,it gives me proper usage but sometimes it throws NullPointerException for this method.

Error in UsageTestService:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1626)
at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1573)
at android.net.INetworkStatsSession$Stub$Proxy.getSummaryForAllUid 
(INetworkStatsSession.java:355)
at android.app.usage.NetworkStats.startSummaryEnumeration 
(NetworkStats.java:330)
at android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager.querySummary 
(NetworkStatsManager.java:166)
at com.test.services.UsageTestService$1.run (UsageTestService.java:172)
```

My code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            NetworkStats networkStats = null;
                            try {

                                networkStatsManager = (NetworkStatsManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE);
                                networkStats = networkStatsManager.querySummary(0, getSubscriberId(UsageTestService.this, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE), 0, System.currentTimeMillis());

                            } catch (RemoteException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if(networkStats!=null)
                            {

                                while (networkStats.hasNextBucket()) {

                                    NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
                                    networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);

                                    int uid = bucket.getUid();
                                    double rx1 = bucket.getRxBytes();
                                    double tx1 = bucket.getTxBytes();
                                    int state1 = bucket.getState();
                                    double totalRxTx1 = rx1+ tx1;
                                    }
                                    }
                                    }
```

What will be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @NileshRathod ,here I have added the check if(networkStats!=null) then only it will proceed.

Comment: Probably the data is not available in all the devices?

Comment: @SripadRaj , I think that is not the case.

Comment: is it working for TYPE_WIFI ?

Comment: I didn't check for TYPE_WIFI .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We stumbled to the same issue and it seems to be a platform bug. At the moment, still unfixed in master branch.

This is an excerpt from the current plaform code:

```
        @Override
        public NetworkStats getSummaryForAllUid(
                NetworkTemplate template, long start, long end, boolean includeTags) {
            try {
                @NetworkStatsAccess.Level int accessLevel = checkAccessLevel(mCallingPackage);
                final NetworkStats stats =
                        getUidComplete().getSummary(template, start, end, accessLevel);
                if (includeTags) {
                    final NetworkStats tagStats = getUidTagComplete()
                            .getSummary(template, start, end, accessLevel);
                    stats.combineAllValues(tagStats);
                }
                return stats;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: Track down and fix the cause of this crash and remove this catch block.
                Slog.wtf(TAG, "NullPointerException in getSummaryForAllUid", e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/net/NetworkStatsService.java#L572

Comment: Our app was randomly crashing because of this issue, until we added a try-catch to handle the exception. Luckily collecting network usage data is not a main feature in our app, so it's not a huge problem if it sometimes fails (as long as we avoid the crash). But of course, it would be nice if Google fixed this error.